# Overiding [class] css declaration

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have CSS in a theme that I am using that I need to override only in a specific div. The CSS is:

```
[class] {
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}
```

What I need to do in essence is:

```
#myspecialdiv [class] {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Don't know what the issue is, you should be able to just use `#myspecialdiv { }`. No need for anything fancy.

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville: `overflow` doesn't inherit - he has to set it on all elements with a class within that `div` since there's a rule elsewhere that sets it to all elements with a class.

Comment: Since your “What I need to do in essence” describes the need using a CSS rule, what is the question? Doesn’t it actually describe the need?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably the sanest way to do it without changing the markup... alternatively, see if you can identify all the possible classes that can occur within that `div`, and write a selector with all the possibilities. It may be ridiculous and possibly even infeasible, but you never know the lengths people will go to in order to improve "rendering performance".

It depends on your markup, really. But it also depends on your theme styles; I can't think of any good reason why one would set such arbitrary rules on any element with any `class` attribute:

- Why must all elements with any class hide overflow?
- Why must they have no list styles?
- Why must they have no padding?

Just some food for thought...

Comment: Would mixins such as in less.css offer a viable third way (given it's not added only for that one issue)? Although I have to admit I don't quite get the issue here.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Neither do I.